# Определение и вызов стрелочной функции в коде

Tags: javascript

Есть код:

```
function fillItems(count, min, max) {
    var items = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
        items.push({
            value: r,
            description: (() => { // <=======
                if (0 === r % 7)
                    return "multiple of 7";
                if (0 === r % 5)
                    return "multiple of 5";
                if (0 === r % 3)
                    return "multiple of 3";
                return "other";
            })()
        });
    }
    return items;
}
```

Вопрос: нормально ли использовать стрелочную функцию в таком виде (отмечено в комментарии), т.е. определить и сразу же ее визвать? Какие могут быть минусы такого кода? Функция используется только в одном месте, ее код сильно упрощен для более легкого восприятия.

Updated: Что бы вы подумали/сказали, увидев такой код у себя в проекте?

Comment: Код делает то, что Вам надо?

Comment: Да. Меня смущает его "правильность" и читабельность, а также возможное наличие "подводных камней".

Comment: Смертельной ошибки нет. Ну она кучу раз создается и вызывается в цикле, что не есть хорошо. Хотя скорее всего движки JS оптимизируют такие вызовы. Не уверен - нужно проверять. Если она "сильно упрощена" - бывает неприятно редактировать и вникать в длинную функцию с такой вложенностью... Можно было `description: describe(r),` и в другом месте свободно писать длинную `function describe(r) {  }`.

Comment: на дворе 20й год уже, поддержка стрелочной функции уже достаточно хорошая

Comment: Независимо от приемлемости IIFE в этом месте. Возможно, стоит поменять местами операнды в сравнениях, не то такой порядок многими считается ненормальным: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/yoda

Comment: @vsemozhebuty спасибо за IIFE

Comment: Я бы удивилися, зачем такое усложенение. `description` можно вычислить спокойно после определения `r`. Я считаю, что не надо усложнять код.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko код чисто для примера. Интересно, а как бы вы вычислили `description`?

Comment: Я бы вычислял его не в IIFE, потому что это усложняет код и я не вижу ни одной причины для использования IIFE.